# Expand and collapse row for ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying to achieve an expand and collapse row for `ng-grid`.

Basically what we have to do, if you click on a row it displayed with more detail.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty example. This is not specific to ngGrid but I believe the concept should carry over. (IF not please feel free to yell at me :) )

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat-start="item in items" ng-click="item.expanded = !item.expanded"></div>

<div class="row-details" ng-if="item.expanded"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Danny, but its not work for ng-grid. The expendable contain may be differ by row and it changed at run time on row select.

Answer (score 0):

Currently nggrid doesn't support this feature [issue #1111](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/1111) and its being implemented in UIGrid 3.0 version.

But i have found a workaround and this is how you can try to achieve in nggrid using rowTemplate and a little bit of jquery. hope this helps!

**rowTemplate**:

```
<div class="row">
// add column data
// expand or collapse image
  <div class=\"col-xs-1 col-md-1\"><img "id='showHide_{{row.rowIndex}}' ng-src='src/img/{{imgArrowRight}}' ng-click=\"rowExpand (row.rowIndex);\"/></div>
</div>

<div id='expRowId_{{row.rowIndex}}' style=\"display:none;\">< div class=\"expData\">< span ng-bind=\"row.entity.Attr\">< /span>
    //add whatever you want in the expanded row.< /div>< /div>
    //Defined customArray for handling dynamic row Toggle

     angular.forEach($scope.gridData, function(row,index) {
         $scope.customArray[index] = true;
     });

    //row expand code

    $scope.rowExpand = function(index){
        $scope.customArray[index] = $scope.customArray[index] === false ? true : false;

        if($scope.customArray[index]){
            $('#showHide_'+index).attr('src','src/assets/img/rigthIcon.gif');
            $('#expRowId_'+index).hide();
        }else{
            $('#showHide_'+index).attr('src','src/assets/img/downIcon.gif');
            $('#expRowId_'+index).show();
        }
    }
```

Also override ngRow styleclass

```
.ngRow {
    position: relative !important;
}
```